# How to Get current charge percentage in decimal in java for android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, battery

I need to get the current charge percentage in decimal values like -> 50.3,20.4,etc...

Is there any way to do the same in android with Kotlin/Java.

Anyone Please help me with this.

Algorithm / Code to get the Current battery Percentage in Decimals.
like 15.2 like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager)getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
int batteryLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
float batteryPercent = batteryLevel / 100f;
```

Comment: Still no change bro

I am getting the charge % as 0.57 if the charge is 57

But I neet it like 57.3,57.4 and so on

Comment: This is clearly wrong.  `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY` is documented as "Remaining battery capacity as an integer percentage of total capacity (with no fractional part)."